# Como hacer que se autoejecute un codigo en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Buenas tengo un código para autocomprar una cosa cuando este en stock nuevamente, pero cuando no está el botón en la página correcto salta un error y no se vuelve a ejecutar el código nuevamente.

¿Cómo se podría hacer para que en caso de que no estuviera el botón `"//*[@id="btnsWishAddBuy"]/button[3]"` se reinicie el script y que cuando dé click al botón de pago `"boton-pago"` se cierre el script y no lo vuelva a ejecutar?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from config import keys
import time

def timeme(method):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        startTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        endTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        print((endTime - startTime)/1000, 's')
        return result
    return wrapper

# will cookies improve load time?
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=www.pccomponentes.com')


@timeme
def order():
    # add to cart
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnsWishAddBuy"]/button[3]').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="GTM-carrito-realizarPedidoPaso1"]').click()
    # Login
    time.sleep(0.3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-form"]/div[4]/div/input').send_keys(keys['email'])
    time.sleep(0.2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-form"]/div[5]/div/div/input').send_keys(keys['pass'])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-form"]/button[2]/div').click()

    # fill out checkout screen fields
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cardform"]/input[1]').send_keys(keys['name'])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cardform"]/fieldset[1]/input').send_keys(keys['card_number'])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cardform"]/fieldset[2]/div[1]/select').send_keys(keys['mes'])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cardform"]/fieldset[2]/div[2]/select').send_keys(keys['year'])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cardform"]/fieldset[3]/div[1]/input').send_keys(keys['card_cvv'])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cardform"]/input[3]').click()
    time.sleep(3.2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ticket-pago"]/p/label/span').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('boton-pago').click()



if __name__ == '__main__':
        # load chrome
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

    # get product url
    driver.get(keys['product_url'])
    order()
```

Comment: No es buena idea que el script se vuelva a autoejecutar. Mejor que sea el sistema operativo quién controle los reinicios. De todas formas, ¿por qué no chequeas si está el botón antes de darle al click? Dejas la ejecución en un bucle de espera hasta que aparezca el botón de stock.

Comment: no se como hacer eso, soy novato en python por eso estaba preguntando xD

Answer (score 1):

Deberías empezar a introducirte en el concepto de "Recursividad". Por definición, algo recurrente es algo que vuelve a ocurrir o a aparecer especialmente despues de un intervalo o un proceso que se repite.
Ademas sumarle un manejo de excepciones para que no se detenga tu script.

Un ejemplo simple podría ser el siguiente...

```
def suma(var):
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        raise Exception #Forzamos una excepción para probar.. aquí iría el script que te causa que el código se detenga.
    except:
        x = var +1
        print(x)
        suma(x) #Recursión
        time.sleep(2)
        
suma(0) #Inicia el método y finalizará cuando la prueba (try) se ejecute correctamente
```

Espero que te sirva. Salu3

PD: Algo que podrías hacer para que no tengas que lidiar con tiempos de espera si es que se ejecutan varias lineas al mismo tiempo es hacer un threading.
Esto quiere decir que separarias en un hilo de procesamiento la recursion para no tener que esperar el time.sleep().

Lo podrías hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
import time 
import threading

def suma(var):
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        raise Exception
    except:
        x = var +1
        print(x)
        suma(x) #Recursión
        time.sleep(2)
        
threading.Thread(target=suma,args=(0,)).start() #Separar en un hilo hasta que la prueba (try) se ejecute correctamente
```

Answer (score 1):

Los métodos para localizar elementos, tales como `find_element_by_xpath`, devuelven la excepción `NoSuchElementException` si no han encontrado ningún elemento.

En python, las excepciones se pueden interceptar con una sentencia `try..except`:

```py
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnsWishAddBuy"]/button[3]').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No he encontrado el botón")
```

Esto tendrías que repetirlo para cada uno de los elementos que buscas y que podrían fallar.

Supongamos que queremos chequear el botón hasta que aparezca. Podríamos hacer algo así:

```py
existe_boton = False
while not aparece:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnsWishAddBuy"]/button[3]').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        time.sleep(5)  # espera 5 segundos antes de repetir la búsqueda
        continue
    else:
        existe_boton = True
```

Se queda en un bucle infinito esperando cada 5 segundo a que aparezca el botón. La variable `existe_boton` controla el final del bucle.

Un modo mucho mejor de hacer la espera es usar el método `WebDriverWait` que, además, está preparado para ignorar excepciones (por defecto ignora `NoSuchElementException`). Para hacer que espere 1000 segundos a que aparezca el botón:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000)  # espera de 1000 segundos

boton = wait.until(lambda drv: drv.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnsWishAddBuy"]/button[3]'))
boton.click()
```